# Dll asociada a un API object solo se genera con rebuild all

Tags: genexus

Cuando creo un api object y hago un build, se genera la dll asociada.

Luego si modifico el objeto api, tengo que hacer un rebuild all para que se vuelva a generar.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Esto se soluciona colocando la preferencia "Generate Developer Menu Make File" = Yes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Donde se realiza esto?, por que no agregar una imagen?, te sugerimos aportar mayor información, ya que esta publicación está reportada como de "baja calidad", revisar [ask], saludos